# Importing csv data into odoo/postgresql from command line

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

I am using Odoo on cloud instance, trying to import csv file from command line, when I tried to import it from psql to "crm.lead" table they are imported but the data does show up in Odoo application.

```
      COPY res_partner(name, website,email,phone)
      FROM '/home/ubuntu/sample/data.csv'
      WITH DELIMITER ','
      CSV HEADER;

     templ=# SELECT count(*) FROM res_partner;
     count 
     -------
     25647
    (1 row)
```

But in customers(Odoo) I can't find the data.
I also tried some python script from some other sources

(http://www.firstclasscomputerconsulting.com/OpenERP/OpenERP70Videos/tabid/145/articleType/ArticleView/articleId/3/Import-data-into-OpenERP-7-using-direct-PostGRES-method.aspx)

but nothing works in my case. need some help.

Answer (score 0):

```
COPY table_name FROM '/path/to/csv/csv_file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV;
```

This query you can directly execute on postgresql as well as you can execute from python code.

Comment: There are two things to mention: the input file must be stored on the **server** where Postgres is running. And the user running this must be a superuser (e.g. `postgres`)

Comment: I used the same query to insert the csv data and data is inserted, but it doesn't show up in Odoo application

Comment: @Maddy: did you `commit` your statement?

Comment: I did the commit, data inserted does'nt sync with the application, although my user :odoo and some database in odoo

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a `customer` field in CSV and set it to `t` in your csv to show in the customer fields.